# How to read Json with two objects?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a Json with the following format:

```
    [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "premio": "Fusca 74",
        "modelo": "Fusca 74",
        "descricao": "Fusca ano 1974 lindo\r\nFusca de colecionador Raríssimo  ",
        "marca": "VolksWagen",
        "pontos": "5000",
        "foto": "/uploads/premios/1120735490945317.jpg",
        "pontos_usuario": "30000"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "premio": "Carro VW",
        "modelo": "Modelo",
        "descricao": "Lindo carro VW",
        "marca": "VW",
        "pontos": "100000",
        "foto": "sistema/uploads/premios/17937693505959.jpg",
        "pontos_usuario": "30000"
    }
]
```

But when the user is not logged in the API needs to return this json

```
{
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Access denied.",
    "error": "Signature verification failed"
}
```

How could I join the 2? To know when the user is logged back code 200 and not logged 401

```
[
    {
        "status": "200"
    },
    {
        "id": "1",
        "premio": "Fusca 74",
        "modelo": "Fusca 74",
        "descricao": "Fusca ano 1974 lindo\r\nFusca de colecionador Raríssimo  ",
        "marca": "VolksWagen",
        "pontos": "5000",
        "foto": "sistema/uploads/premios/1120735490945317.jpg",
        "pontos_usuario": "30000"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "premio": "Carro VW",
        "modelo": "Modelo",
        "descricao": "Lindo carro VW",
        "marca": "VW",
        "pontos": "100000",
        "foto": "sistema/uploads/premios/17937693505959.jpg",
        "pontos_usuario": "30000"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "premio": "Palmas",
        "modelo": "Modelo",
        "descricao": "Teste",
        "marca": "OEA",
        "pontos": "20000",
        "foto": "sistema/uploads/premios/3091828554641303.png",
        "pontos_usuario": "30000"
    }
]
```

Summarizing: When the user is logged in, a list of prizes will be presented and the status 200, when it is not returned status 401

```
$.post('service_premium.php',JSON.stringify({ jwt:jwt }), function(data) {


    if(data.status===200){


        $.each(data, function(index, value){
            tot_pontos = value.pontos_usuario;

        }
        }
})
.done(function() { console.log('getJSON request done!'); })
.fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(xhr.responseText); })
//.fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(xhr.responseText); });
.always(function() { console.log('getJSON request ended!'); });
});
```

My PHP

```
if($count > 0){
                $premios = array();
                //$curso_eventos["data"] = array();
                //$curso_eventos["count"] = $count;
                array_push($premios,array("status" => "200"));


                while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                    extract($row);

                    $p  = array(
                    "id" => $id,
                    "premio" => $premio,
                    "modelo" => $modelo,
                    "descricao" => $descricao,
                    "marca" => $marca,
                    "pontos" => $pontos,
                    "foto" => $foto,
                    "pontos_usuario" => $pontos_usuario

                    );


                    array_push($premios, $p);
                    //array_push($curso_eventos["data"], $p);
                }

                echo json_encode($premios);
            }
enter code here
```

Comment: But Will, from your description status 200 is implied if you have data, so why would you need to add ?

Comment: Bib, In fact, I need to have 2 levels in this 1st Level Json as 200 or 401 and 2nd Level with List of prizes.
But when the user is not logged in he will only bring level 1

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but a normal behaviour would be to always return a status and data in another property if available.

Something like:

```
{
  "status": "200",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "premio": "Fusca 74",
      "modelo": "Fusca 74",
      "descricao": "Fusca ano 1974 lindo\r\nFusca de colecionador Raríssimo  ",
      "marca": "VolksWagen",
      "pontos": "5000",
      "foto": "sistema/uploads/premios/1120735490945317.jpg",
      "pontos_usuario": "30000"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "premio": "Carro VW",
      "modelo": "Modelo",
      "descricao": "Lindo carro VW",
      "marca": "VW",
      "pontos": "100000",
      "foto": "sistema/uploads/premios/17937693505959.jpg",
      "pontos_usuario": "30000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How do I read this with:

$ .post ('service_premium.php', JSON.stringify ({jwt: jwt}), function (data) {
jQuery.parseJSON (JSON.stringify (data));

$ .each (data, function (index, value) {

}

Comment: In this json I have 2 levels

Comment: Please help me mount php? I just put a piece of code, and also called ajax? how can I read the status and then the loop repeat?